# sets proving question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Suppose A and B are two sets with (A × B) ∪ (B × A) = A × A. Prove that A ⊆ B"

I'm having problem with solving this question... Can anyone give me any tips？

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x\in A$. Then $(x,x)\in A\times A$. So $(x,x)\in (A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$, i.e. $(x,x)\in (A\times B)$ or $(x,x)\in (B\times A)$. Now you can complete the proof.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you!